# Keeping true size on UV maps

Tags: uv-image-editor

I'm trying to unwrap my UV map to the correct size - it is in my layout page.

It may be a bit of an odd one what I'm trying to use Blender for.

We are trying to create visual layouts for customers where we can show them what the job will look like. We have a sized image of a marble slab and have sized templates (.dxf) which we have converted to mesh.

The sizes are both correct but when I unwrap them, they are not the correct size. I've tried Normal unwrap, Smart UV Project, Project from view, etc., but nothing seems to give me the correct size.

Comment: How should it give the correct size? A UV map has a normalized 2-dimensional coordinate system, it goes from (0, 0) in the bottom left corner to (1, 1) in the top right. And this is independent from any image size or image ratio. If you have a square image the top right will be (1, 1) and if the ratio is 16:9 the coordinates in the top right are still (1, 1). And using the automatic unwrapping methods will most likely result in Blender trying to match the UVs to fill the map, no matter if the object you unwrap is gigantic or tiny.

Comment: Cheers Gordon so will it not be possible to do it to the correct size do you think? cheers